# Trying to detect if tableview scroll is over indexpath.row 0

Tags: ios, uitableview, refresh, tableview

I am trying to determine if a user has scrolled beyond the top of the table so that I can refresh it. So far, I have been unsuccessful because I seem to be getting a unique situation:

```
if (indexPath.row < 0) {
```

the above does not work.

```
 if (_tableView.contentOffset.y < -64) {
```

This works, but only when you pull extremely far (pull all content to the bottom of the tableview for it to work). Somehow I need to make it so they only need to pull a little bit, but oddly enough, when I put it at -63 it reacts as though it is at -64 and continually refreshes.

```
if(self.tableView.contentOffset.y < (self.tableView.contentSize.height - self.tableView.bounds.size.height))
{
```

This works, but only when you pull extremely far (pull all content to the bottom of the tableview for it to work). Somehow I need to make it so they only need to pull a little bit, but oddly enough, when I put it at -63 it reacts as though it is at -64 and continually refreshes.

Comment: You are going to need to setup a variable that says "Hey, I already updated this interaction".  Set that to false at the beginning of scrolling, then set it to true when you refresh.  Then set it to false again when the interaction stops.

Comment: Or just use a [UIRefreshControl](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIRefreshControl_class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: This is what you are looking for - https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/egotableviewpullrefresh